# Docker with SQL Server cannot insert values into database with sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, docker

I have a docker file where I import two databases.

```
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server

    RUN mkdir -p /var/opt/mssql/backup
    COPY clean_SCManager.bak /var/opt/mssql/backup/SCManager.bak
    COPY clean_SCServer.bak /var/opt/mssql/backup/SCServer.bak
    COPY SCManager-setup.sql /var/opt/mssql/SCManager-setup.sql
    COPY startup.sh /var/opt/mssql/startup.sh

    ENV MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=P@ssw0rd
    ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y

    RUN chmod +x  /var/opt/mssql/startup.sh
    CMD /var/opt/mssql/startup.sh

    EXPOSE 1433
```

Now I want to insert some values into one of my databases, for that I am using a SQL file which contains a `INSERT INTO` command.

```
    USE SCManager;
    GO

    INSERT INTO epls_dbo.Account("uid", "login", "password_hash", "lastLogin", "failedLogins", "locked", "role", "locale", "accountPenIdUid") 
    VALUES (4294967306, 'sysadm', '2398ef2774cd07f31037e9347de3e660', '2017-09-12 14:50:35.607', 0, 'False', 'Admin', 'en_US', NULL);
```

This SQL will be called by a bash script, in this I am using `sqlcmd` to execute the SQL script.

```
    #/bin/bash
    echo "startup.sh is called, starting sqlserver"
    /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr &
    echo "start sleeping for 20 seconds"
    sleep 20
    echo "sleeping done"

    /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P "P@ssw0rd" -Q "RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/backup/SCServer.bak'"
    /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P "P@ssw0rd" -Q "RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/backup/SCManager.bak'"
    /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P "P@ssw0rd" -Q "RESTORE DATABASE SCManager FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/backup/SCManager.bak' WITH MOVE 'SCManager' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/SCManager.mdf', MOVE 'SCManager_log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/SCManager_log.ldf'"
    /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P "P@ssw0rd" -Q "RESTORE DATABASE SCServer FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/backup/SCServer.bak' WITH MOVE 'SCServer' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/SCServer.mdf', MOVE 'SCServer_log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/SCServer_log.ldf'"
    sleep 10
    /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -d SCManager -P "P@ssw0rd" -i "/var/opt/mssql/SCManager-setup.sql"

    tail -f /dev/null
```

When I run the docker image I can see in the logs that the database has been imported and that the sql file has been executed but the sql has not been successfully executed

```
    Changed database context to 'SCManager'.
```

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server fb5db2041be5, Line 4
>   Invalid column name 'uid'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server fb5db2041be5, Line 4
>   Invalid column name 'login'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server fb5db2041be5, Line 4
>   Invalid column name 'password_hash'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server fb5db2041be5, Line 4
>   Invalid column name 'lastLogin'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server fb5db2041be5, Line 4
>   Invalid column name 'failedLogins'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server fb5db2041be5, Line 4
>   Invalid column name 'locked'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server fb5db2041be5, Line 4
>   Invalid column name 'role'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server fb5db2041be5, Line 4
>   Invalid column name 'locale'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server fb5db2041be5, Line 4
>   Invalid column name 'accountPenIdUid'.

When I connect to the running docker container I can query the database, so the database is available and the table which I want to insert into exits

```
root@fb5db2041be5:/# /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P "P@ssw0rd" -d SCManager -Q "select * from epls_dbo.Account"
    uid                  login                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            password_hash                    lastLogin               failedLogins locked role
                                  locale accountPenIdUid
    -------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------- ----------------------- ------------ ------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------ --------------------

    (0 rows affected)
```

Also I can execute in the bash my insert into command an it inserts correctly the values, why does it not work by calling it from my bash script?

Comment: THis points to a problem in the script, nothing that has to do with Docker or SQL Server itself. The errors complain that those columns are missing. Are you sure you're targeting the *correct* database? What is the table's schema (CREATE TABLE statement)?

Comment: Looks like the script was created for a database version a different schema (ie tables, columns) than the one you restored. You should locate the correct backup file or fix the SQL script

Comment: You're using quoted identifiers, but without specifying `-I` to turn on the `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` option, which will get you exactly this error. T-SQL's native quoting (`[column]`) will work regardless of this option.

Comment: I understand that you suggest to use the Option -I so I changed my startup.sh with this line /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -I -S localhost -U SA -d SCManager -P "P@ssw0rd" -i "/var/opt/mssql/SCManager-setup.sql" there is still the same error

Comment: My fault, your hint with -I is working. Thanks